# Inserting non-number rows in MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data-frame with multiple features, where I would like to insert rows of nans corresponding to only the first feature. In other words, I would like to transform something like this:
[image]

into this:
[image]

As I will be dealing with large datasets, the speed is important.

Comment: create the dataframe and concat sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general solution for select missing values if more columns add new DataFrame created by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), selecting `feature`s columns and rewritten data in `feat2`, so if use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) are all another columns replaced to missing values. Last for correct order add [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('feat1')[['feat1','feat2']].assign(feat2='-')
df2 = (pd.concat([df1, df], sort=False, ignore_index=True)
         .sort_values('feat1'))

print (df2)
   feat1 feat2  var
0      A     -  NaN
3      A     x  0.0
4      A     y  1.0
5      A     z  2.0
1      B     -  NaN
6      B     x  3.0
7      B     y  4.0
8      B     z  5.0
2      C     -  NaN
9      C     x  6.0
10     C     y  7.0
11     C     z  8.0
```

Comment: How would it work, if I have more than two feature columns?

Comment: @Vadim - Give me a sec.

Comment: @Vadim - Answer working also for more columns, for mre features anly change `[['feat1','feat2']].assign(feat2='-')` to `[['feat1','feat2', 'feat3']].assign(feat2='-',feat3='-')`